# What is the jQuery procedure of appending to a string instead of replacing it?

Tags: jquery, string, append

I was converting some of my raw Javascript codes to jQuery and I encounter some lines that goes like this -

```
divRecentNames.innerHTML += "SOMETHING";
```

I'm trying to use the `.html()` method, but all it does is replace the existing value with a new one.

```
divRecentNames.html("SOMETHING");
```

What is the jQuery equivalent of appending a new string to an already existing one?

Comment: `divRecentNames.append("SOMETHING");`

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/append. BTW what is `divRecentNames` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#elementId').append("This will be append");
```

[official document](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for `append` method
**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/ZUZ36/

Comment: what does this explains to OP..?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append()` in jquery appending a new string to an already existing one.

```
divRecentNames.append("SOMETHING");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this : This will append the new text to the existing one.

```
$(divRecentNames).append("SOMETHING");
```

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8nnx/11/)**

[.append() API doc](http://api.jquery.com/append/)